# Allow to the user enter a value to an TColorBox Component

Tags: delphi

i have a [TColorBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TColorBox) component on  my form and i want which the user enter directly (type) a value in the component in the same way when i edit a TColor property in the object inspector.
the question is, is posible set the TColorBox to allow to the user edit the color value manually and set the Tcolorbox component to show the value typed in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a plain vanilla `TColorBox` to allow in-place editing.

You'll have to either write your own or look for a 3rd party that offers that functionality (there must be many that do).